# comparison between point and integer

Tags: objective-c, time, numbers, if-statement

Right, basically I want to add two numbers together. It's for a working hours calculator and I've included parameters for a night shift scenario as an if statement. However, it now mucks up the day shift pattern. So I want to sort out that if the start time is below 12, then it'll revert to the original equation shown in the code instead of the if statement.

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    int result = [finishHours.text intValue] - [startHours.text intValue];
    totalHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result];
    if (result < 0) {
            totalHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result * -1];

    }
    if (result < 12) {
            totalHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result + 24];
    }
    if (startHours < 12) {
            totalHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result - 24];
    }
```

Comment: You might want to tag this with the language (C#?).

Comment: Also specify exactly what behavior you expect, and what behavior you get, including any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Both of those if statements are going to happen for result.  I would suggest an if statement that includes greater than zero and less than 12.

```
if((result >= 0) && (result < 12))
{
totalHours.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", result + 24];
}
```